# how to fix http 500 error and blob file is not uploading

Tags: jsp, web, servlets, web-development-server

`post` and `doPost` in jsp and servlet resp. are not working instead get and services is working. 
And blob image file is also not uploading.

jsp code:

```
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="insertbooks">
```

servlet code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");


//retrieving image
        InputStream inputStream = null; // input stream of the upload file

        String Title = request.getParameter("title");

         // obtains the upload file part in this multipart request
        Part filePart = request.getPart("image");
        if (filePart != null) {
            // prints out some information for debugging
            System.out.println(filePart.getName());
            System.out.println(filePart.getSize());
            System.out.println(filePart.getContentType());

            // obtains input stream of the upload file
            inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();

              pw.println("Got photooo");
        }


        String Author = request.getParameter("author");
        String Price = request.getParameter("price");

        float Pricef = Float.valueOf(Price);
          pw.println("Got parameters");




Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

      try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

      pw.println("Driver Loaded");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUser, dbPass); 
      pw.println("Connection Established_1");
      stmt = conn.createStatement();

     // String query = "Insert into books(title,image,author,price) values('"+Title +"','"+inputStream +"','"+Author+"','"+Pricef +"')" ;
     String query = "Insert into books(title,image,author,price) values(?,?,?,?)" ;

     PreparedStatement ps =conn.prepareStatement(query);
     ps.setNString(1,Title);
     if(inputStream != null){
     // fetches input stream of the upload file for the blob column
     ps.setBinaryStream(2, inputStream);
     }
     ps.setNString(3,Author);
     ps.setFloat(4, Pricef);



     // Sends the statement to the database server
     int row= ps.executeUpdate();
     if(row>0){
     pw.println("data inserted");

     }


     /*int row = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
            if (row > 0) {

                pw.println("Data Inserted");
            }  */


      } catch (SQLException ex) {
             ex.getMessage();
          //  ex.printStackTrace();
          ex.printStackTrace(pw);
            pw.println("Connection not Established_1");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(insertbooks.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                // closes the database connection
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Successfully");
            // sets the message in request scope
          //  request.setAttribute("message", message);

            // forwards to the message page
           // getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/message.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }

    pw.close();
    }
}
```

error:

HTTP Status 500 -
type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from 
  fulfilling this request.

exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
 sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1838)
  sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
  java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:451)
  java.lang.Float.valueOf(Float.java:416)
  insertbooks.doPost(insertbooks.java:63)
  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
  org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: post your full error logs

Comment: i have posted error

Comment: what does `Price` contain,did you print it ?

Comment: <input type="text" style="width:300px;height:25px" name="price" placeholder="Enter price"/>

Comment: String Pricef = request.getParameter("price");
        
        //float Pricef = Float.valueOf(Price);

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 2
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)

Comment: try to print value of  `Pricef` and see if it have something or not ,because you have `java.lang.NullPointerException` ,which mean value is null

Comment: at insertbooks.doPost(insertbooks.java:97)

Comment: `System.out.println(filePart.getName());
            System.out.println(filePart.getSize());
            System.out.println(filePart.getContentType());` ,does this lines got printing ?

Comment: no printing , price is null

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 insertbooks.doPost(insertbooks.java:59)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Comment: check why it is null ,,then it should solve your problem.